# How to extract part of string using regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a url and I want to extract the last part of my url using regular expression
My url is as follows

```
http://Experteer Country Version 1/vacancies/europe/jobs/city_name_1
```

I want to extract the last portion "city_name_1"

How can I extract it

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "http://Experteer Country Version 1/vacancies/europe/jobs/city_name_1"
last_part = s.split('/').last
# => city_name_1
```

No regexes required.

Comment: So you mean the last_part will be equal to city_name_1 ?

Comment: Can you please help me in my other question that I posted today about rspec ?

Comment: Done :) Please help me in my question regarding rspec if you can ... I will be highly thankful to you

Comment: @gikian: posted a comment there. It'll help you :-)

Comment: Just a note: I find `.last` is more intention-revealing than `[-1]`, so `last_part = s.split('/').last`